# smptlib returns does not deliver emails using Comcast - but works with Gmail, no errors present

Tags: python, email, smtplib

This code was working perfectly, until earlier this week. Not sure if something changed with Comcast or on our end. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue are appreciated!

```
import smtplib

ssl_port = 587
email_sever = 'smtp.comcast.net'
login = 'login@comcast.net'
password = 'password123'

smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp_obj.connect(email_server,ssl_port)
smtp_obj.set_debuglevel(1)
smtp_obj.starttls()
smtp_obj.login(login,password)
smtp_obj.sendmail(login,['sentto@gmail.com'],"text to send in email")
smtp_obj.quit()
```

The debug output indicates all recipients are 'ok' and that the mail has been 'accepted for delivery' with no errors.

smtp_obj.sendmail command returns {} indicating no errors.

This same code is used passing in Gmail credentials and works...

Comment: The bare unquoted strings are almost certainly syntax errors unless you have code else here which declares a variable `smtp` which has attributes `comcast.net` etc.

Comment: Fixed those errors, it was a typo on my part copying over the code.

Comment: SMTP is a store-and-forward relay architecture; it is entirely possible that the Comcast server is sitting on the messages for a week, though the envelope sender should eventually see a bounce message if they can't be delivered. If `login@comcast.net` is yours, see if it has received messages from `MAILER_DAEMON`.

Comment: It is also entirely possible that the messages were delivered to Gmail, who then moved them to a spam folder, or whatever.

Comment: I checked the email and I do not have anything from MAILER_DAEMON, and nothing in my spam/junk folders. Would there be something wrong with the port connections? Do you know of any checks I could do to investigate further? I am new to email servers, but am very familiar with python, so this is a bit of a challenge.

Comment: Proper troubleshooting would require access to mail logs. Maybe send to a mail server whose admin you are friendly with rather than the black hole that is Gmail.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to send to a server where I have admin privileges. In looking at the message trace logs I do not have any emails from the Comcast email. The Comcast email can, however, send emails from Outlook, it just not delivering them when used through stmplib.

Comment: Again, if Comcast accepts the message, it's then their responsibility and their debug effor to figure out what happens next.

Comment: I contacted Comcast and they put the blame on the python module (which I know is not the issue). I also tried using a different Comcast email account to send the emails and the same issue occurred - a successful run of the script, but emails are not delivered.